# Changing the form action, when a submit button is pressed using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a submit button like as follows.

```
<input type="submit" 
       name="btnDelete" 
       id="btnDelete" 
       value="Delete" 
       onclick="this.form.action='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Country/DeleteMany'"/>
```

I causes the form action to change, when it is pressed.

---

I however, need to invoke another function before this action is changed. This another function returns a boolean value based on a confirm dialog of JavaScript.

I have tried the following.

```
onclick="return confirmDeleteMuliple(); this.form.action='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Country/DeleteMany'"
```

The action however, did not change on submit (when `confirmDeleteMuliple()` returns true).

---

I have tried placing the code that changes the action in a separate JavaScript function like as follows.

```
function deleteManyAction()
{
    document.dataForm.action='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Country/DeleteMany';
}
```

And the `onclick` attribute is changed as follows.

```
onclick="return confirmDeleteMuliple();deleteManyAction();"
```

The `deleteManyAction()` function however, never invoked. It works only when the function `confirmDeleteMuliple()` is removed from `onclick`.

How to invoke these two functions in the defined sequence?

<sub>The expression `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` evaluates to a context path of the application on load time like `/Example` (when this file (JSP) is parsed).</sub>

Comment: It seems you are looking for `onsubmit` event of javascript..

Comment: Anyway, the action should be changed after confirmation (after `confirmDeleteMuliple()` returns true. Otherwise, nothing should happen).

Comment: Then you should call the next function in `confirmDeleteMultiple` function when it is returning true.

Comment: How do you not know what the `return` statement does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code placed after a `return` will never be reached. The `return` basically means stop working and give me what you have.

This should do what you want:

```
onclick="return submit();"

function submit(){
   if(confirmDeleteMuliple()){
       deleteManyAction();
       return true;
   }else{
       return false; //Otherwise the form will be submitted anyway.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to keep code (JS) out of your presentation layer (HTML).  I assign all of my event handlers in my JS files.  Try this approach, which I think will make your code :

```
$("#btnDelete").click(function() {
    if ( confirmDeleteMuliple() ) {
       this.closest("form").attr("action", 
                                 ${pageContext.request.contextPath} + '/Country/DeleteMany');
       # Here, returning true will allow the form submission to complete with the new
       return true;
    } else {
       # This will stop the form from being submitted
       return false;
    }
});
```